# Openssl: Unable to download certificate with altered port

Tags: openssl, certificates

I am downloading FTPS certificate from server using following command:

```
echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 192.168.1.88:990
```

Certificate get downloaded as expected.

Now, on server side, if I change the default port `990` to some unused port `100`, and again use the same command as above with new port, then an error occurs.

```
echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 192.168.1.88:100
```

Error says:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)

3076294336:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:796:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 307 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1470134380
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

How can I download the FTPS certificate from server when default port is changed ?

(Though, I am asking about FTPS, same problem also exist for HTTPS only. But Now I am concern about FTPS only)

Comment: look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166950/unable-to-establish-ssl-connection-how-do-i-fix-my-ssl-cert

Comment: Your client isn't seeing an SSL service which either means that your server is misconfigured (not presenting as SSL) or something (firewall? proxy server?) is intercepting the connection and not letting it reach the end point properly.

Comment: @StephenHarris How do I confirm that it's misconfigured server. As I do *NOT* have any firewall or proxy in between.